# SQL statement that checks if a table value is contained within a string I send it

Tags: sql, github, heroku

I know about the LIKE operator, but for what im trying to do, I would need to swap the column with the value, which didn't work.

Im using this in a discord bot that is connected to a database with a table. The table has two columns, keyword and response. I need a query that could give me the response when a given string contains the keyword.

```
SELECT response FROM Reply WHERE (insert something here to see if provided string 
contains table value)
```

Comment: You have given way too little information here to receive any sort of meaningful answer.  Please show us the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the `SQL` tag indicates your question relates to standard SQL (hover over the tag and read it).

LIKE cannot be used for your purpose because the standard is quite clear on what you can specify :

```
<character like predicate> ::=
<row value predicand> <character like predicate part 2>
<character like predicate part 2> ::=
[ NOT ] LIKE <character pattern> [ ESCAPE <escape character> ]
```

Therefore you can't `WHERE 'myliteral' LIKE colname`.

So you'd need a scalar function, but I am not aware of any scalar function defined in the standard that you can use for this purpose.

So you are confined to scalar functions offered by your particular DBMS.  E.g. in DB2, there is POSSTR(source_string, search_string) that you could use as POSSTR('myliteral', colname).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 response
from Reply t
where concat('%',keyword,'%') like '<user provided text>'
--using % let check if the keyword is 'contained' in user's text
```

PS CONCAT used this way works on SQLSERVER check the correspondence for the dbms you're using, also top1 stops the query once it finds the first keyword